# removing words from list

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have been using crunch in Kali Linux to create a wordlist that is 10 characters long using the lalphanumeric (a-f 3-9 ) command. I know they're big files so please don't tell me not to do it. I've created the lists using a@@@@@@@@ , then b@@@@@@@@@ and so on.

Now what I need is to remove the words that will have all numbers after the first letter, or that is all letters. For example, remove a123456789 , a587636486 , a888888888...  Or. agdujcjfuf, aaaaaaaaaa..  ( the ones that are all letters or all numbers. I'm assuming this will reduce the size of my wordlist by quite a bit..

But obviously I need to keep all words that have a minimum of 3 numbers or 3letters in thenm.

Can anyone help me with a command.

'rm -i a[0-9]'
.   .    .   .   .   .   .   .  .
'rm -I a[a-z]'.  .  .   perhaps.?

I didn't want to do it until I can confirm first

Comment: Are those "file names" or "lines inside a text file"?. You say: wordlist, but you also say that you need a command: `rm `. The two should be processed differently.

Comment: I ask for command so i can modify the list from a terminal. It's a bunch of words/lines inside a text file.

Comment: A text editor like `nano` should be available for you to "modify the list from a terminal". Just write `nano file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values to remove are inside a text file named `file.txt`.

Write this in a txt file, and store it as `script.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

awk '/^[a-z]*$/ {next}      # Do not print lines that are all lowercase letters.
     /^[A-Z]*$/ {next}      # Do not print lines that are all lowercase letters.
     /^a[0-9]*$/ {next}     # Do not print lines that are an a followed by all numbers.
     /^[a-z][0-9]*$/ {next} # ONE lowercase letter (anyone) followed by numbers.
     {print} ' file.txt > result.txt
```

Then, execute it by writing `bash script.sh` in the command line.

The "program" is using "regular expressions" to select text of a certain structure, and decide what to do when some structure coincides.